# Is there a way to validate if data is true or false in angular when button is clicked?

Tags: angular

The problem is even though my credentials are correct the program gives me a false output, is there any way to fix this?

.TS

```
  loginUser(){
    if(this.uname == "admin"  && this.pass == "admin"){
      alert('Login')
    }else{
      alert('Invalid')
    }
  }
```

The output gives me 'Invalid' which falls in the else how can I make it as true?

Answer (score 0):

Change [id] to [(ngModel)]. Gives you more control and, well, works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are fetching the `[id]=uname` with the `this.uname` but perhaps your not doing it at all and that's why it's saying "Invalid".

Try doing it with [(ngModel)] - it will fetch your `uname` with `this.uname` or even better- try using reactive forms.